# How does MetaMask communicate with the blockchain?

Tags: metamask

I've looked over the source code and cannot for the life of me figure out how MetaMask is accessing the blockchain.  When set to Mainnet, which RPC is it using?

Comment: It connects through Infura.

Comment: Correct, https://infura.io